# My shoes 'make a funny sound' when I walk

Tags: word-request, onomatopoeia

I was reviewing the words I wrote down from movies when I came across the word *squech* and I had two example written next to it, one from a movie and the other probably from a reading.

I remember the scene was showing a sword thrusted at someone across his body and to show the sound of that it was put *(squeching)* under.

The other example goes like this *my shoes squeching when I walk*.

Now I'm searching and I can't find it! I've tried similar words but they don't make sense here. Probably I made a spelling mistake while writing it down and now I feel frustrated. What's the word?

Thanks

Comment: It could be "my shoes *squeak* when I walk". As for the sword, and possibly the shoes, the word might just be an approximation of what the sound is, even if not a real word. You see a lot of this in comic books. See [*Onomatopoeia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia)

Comment: Like a rat squeaks? Well _squeak_ wasn't a new word to me to write down, it can't be it. I must have been a different word.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are we being asked for a verb meaning *[to make] the sound of a thrusting sword?* Perhaps that might be ***swish*** or similar. Or the *sound shoes might make?* If the shoes are wet, ***squelch, squish*** come to mind - if dry, ***creak, squeak***. But what exactly is OP looking for?

Comment: _Squelch_ that's the word. Thanks FumbleFingers I learnt some other words from your comment too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of [squelch](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/squelch_1?q=squelch) or a "wet sucking sound". If you fell into a swimming pool fully dressed, your shoes would squelch as you walked after you got out of the pool.

I remember it by thinking of [squish](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/squish?q=squish) (wet noise) + [belch](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/belch_1?q=belch) (air noise or burp). There are some examples of squelching noises, including "A sword slicing a human, gory" sample, on [this SoundSnap page](http://www.soundsnap.com/tags/squelch?page=1).

Comment: _Squelch_ that's the word. Exactly it was like you put your hand in mud and take it out suddenly. Thanks